# java statement.executeUpdate() returns an update count that is not 1. Sporadically

Tags: java, sql

I  am trying to figure out a piece of code that has existed as is for several years but has recently started behaving differently (not sure if it is because of newer versions of jre or the environment the code is being run in but I don't know enough to tell). Anyways, basically the gist of the code pasted below is that I process one record at a time and insert it into a new table. The idea is that I only ever insert 1 row at a time. This code is from like 2000 or something and back then the engineers decided to throw in super paranoid sanity checks to make sure that one and only one record got inserted into the said table. All of a sudden this piece has been throwing the exceptions that indicate that the number of rows inserted was NOT 1 (Unfortunately, I don't know how many rows got inserted since the code lacks that piece of logging).

```
    //
// If the result set is empty, then get the next master record id and insert a new record into the
// Holding_Tank_Master_Records.
//
if ( !mrRecords.next() )
{
    // a new master record is needed
    mrid = this.getMasterRecordId();

    log.debug("new master record id = " + mrid);

    insertSQL = new String("INSERT INTO Holding_Tank_Master_Records (" +
                        "Master_Record_Id, Probe_Date, Import_Filename, " +
    "Pennies, Nickels, Dimes, Quarters, " +
    "Half_Dollars, SBA_Dollars, One_Dollar_Bills, " +
    "Five_Dollar_Bills, Ten_Dollar_Bills, Twenty_Dollar_Bills) " +
    "VALUES( " + mrid + ", '" + curProbeDate.toString() + "', 'Avail AVL APC', " +
    "0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0 )");                  

    int result = mrStatement.executeUpdate(insertSQL);

    if ( result == 1 )
    {
        log.debug ( "NEW MASTER RECORD created for " + curProbeDate.toString() );
    }
    else
    {
        log.debug("Failed! SQL: " + insertSQL);

    String strErrMsg = "Failed to insert new record into Holding_Tank_Master_Records.  " +
        "Master_Record_Id = " + mrid + " Probe_Date = " + curProbeDate.toString() + 
        "Vehicle Farebox Id = " + Integer.toString(vehicleID) + ".";

        log.error( strErrMsg );
        throw new AvailFaretoolException( strErrMsg );
    }
}
```

So, what I am seeing is the 'Failed!' SQL message along with the custom exception being thrown lending me to believe that the number of rows inserted was NOT 1.

Has anyone seen anything like this before? Can you spot an issue here? By the way, if I were to run the SQL via SQL management studio, it works just fine with a message telling me 1 row was inserted. I know that the SQL running through the code isn't causing any SQL exceptions (which in any case would have caused the code flow to fall straight to my catch block, correct?)

Thanks for looking at this!
K

Edit:
Just wanted to add information regarding research I have done so far on this topic:
The API documentation for the executeUpdate mentions that the 'update count' it returns is either (1) the row count for SQL Data Manipulation Language (DML) statements or (2) 0 for SQL statements that return nothing

Since the statement is a pure insert statement, I don't understand how it could return anything but a non-negative integer. I mean, the only possible outcome of an insert statement is a row count, right?

Comment: So does the row for which you see the error exist in the database? (Assuming the log entry giving you the master record ID, probe date, and vehicle farebox id is sufficient for you to know.)

Comment: Also, if 1 is not being returned what is? If it is returning 0, maybe the record you're trying to insert can't be inserted - duplicate maybe?

Comment: Is it possible that your DBA has changed any table constraints or adjusted the rights of the user your system logs in with?

Comment: You've mentioned SQL Management Studio. Is this MS SQL Server, then?

Comment: Thanks for looking at this.
To answer some of the questions,
 - the entry does not exist but that is because of the the code forces the whole operation to rollback if something fails (this it to maintain some known state of the processing
 - The database schema has not changed for the tables in question in about the same time as the code has existed. This is legacy code that has been constant for years
 - Yes, it is MS SQL server, sorry for leaving that detail out

Comment: Oh, and unfortunately I don't know what value it is returning. And it can't be a duplicate since the master record ID is a primary key and therefore should throw a SQLException of some flavor which I don't see happening.

Comment: Pretty odd that you are not getting an exception and that result is not 1. Next step is to log the value, or run the code in debug to find the value.

Comment: Yup, working on that. Unfortunate that it isn't a guaranteed failure all the time. Will post some additional information if I find something worth sharing. Thanks.

Comment: Ok, so the latest information I have is that the value returned is '-1'! That does not belong in the documentation whatsoever!! Please tell me someone knows what is going on...